# How to correctly handle large media files in a web project?

Tags: vuejs3, storage, vite, file-storage, web-storage

I'm starting a new Vue 3 + Vite project and its a simple landing page.

Its nothing too fancy but I was in doubt what would be the best way to handle media files - especially some large files like background videos or HQ pictures.

Now I have some HQ pictures and images (already as webp and compressed with the largest one with  ~800kb) but I'm a little bit confused about how I should handle the background videos.

I have only a section with video background but using different files sources as the resolution becomes smaller or larger (I read somewhere that is a good practice).

The mobile one has ~3.5mb;

The tablet one has ~5mb;

The desktop one has ~ 8mb;

And the 4k video (yes. The client was specific about that one) about 16mb;

Its a short background-video with 20s in a loop.

But these videos should be in the src directory inside the project or stored in the cloud somewhere like AWS or Youtube?

The total media folder (with everything) is about 40mb size.

Does it make any difference to the end user?

PS: What I managed to find as a result on the internet is quite divided with articles saying how bad it is to leave heavy videos and media files within the project /src and others saying that using AWS or other media hosting systems for a simple project (such as a Single-Page) decrease performance for the end user. So I'm not sure which way to continue.

Comment: You’ll need to distinguish between handling the *repository* like git, where you’ll probably want to use some special large binary storage, and where to deploy the files to on the production server.

Comment: This is a broad topic but to first things off, 4k on a website is totally irrelevant on SOOO many aspects. I'm also quite curious to see if the starting codec is some 4444 XQ with 1GB bandwidth or something alike (or the opposite and the most dodgy 4k video ever). Try to sub-sample it and remove all the invisible stuff baked-in. Overall, hosting your own assets may be fine if they are 300% properly optimized and served in the best supported format. That would require quite some work (if you want to achieve that by yourself) but some services like Cloudinary or MUX may help for that.

Comment: Overall, some advanced filmmaking knowledge may push the boundaries to their full potential but overall, is it something that is desirable on a website? Even more, on a mobile/tablet device? Definitely not. Resolution is one thing, bitrate is another. Google for "youtube ltt 4k" to get a detailed video on why/how 4k is irrelevant on web. And keep in mind that your end user is not an elite "prosummer" that will nitpick for the smallest detail ever. Accessing a page 3 times faster will bring more clients than waiting for a huge asset that will maybe not ever be looked at. YMMW overall.

Comment: @kissu

Thanks a lot for your reply.
I tried to explain to the client in SO MANY WAYS that putting a 4K video on a website would be of no benefit and could even bring harm.
 
The thing is that he wants to open the site on a 4K TV in his office with the background video playing in the background - for some reason he thinks it's good for his clients to see that way - and leave it there all day.

I tried to argue about opening the video on youtube on the TV but to no avail.

Comment: Youtube will have some compression anyway. And...having the video in 1440p will probably go un-noticed for him anyway (as for 95% of the people viewing the video). The solution, wire the TV to a computer or anything with a player like QuickTime Player and let it roll all day long. Can maybe even stream it with a Chromecast or wire a Raspberry to the back of the TV. Also, how is the record made? Does it really benefit from a 4K source? There is "4K" and "4K". One being ugly but having enough pixels, the other making use of them rather than having them duplicated to fill the canvas.